# UWP ToggleButton image depending on IsChecked

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I am trying to give my `ToggleButton` a different image depending on the `IsChecked` state of the `ToggleButton`, but in UWP Style triggers no longer exist, so it has to be done in a different way.

I ran into discussions where the supposed solution is to use `DataTriggerBehavior`, but I am getting nowhere.

What I want to achieve (blue is unchecked, green is checked):

[image]

[image]

Is the following in the good direction?

```
<ToggleButton 
    x:Name="ToggleButton"
    IsChecked="{Binding SignalButtonSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Command="{Binding SignalButtonCommand}">
    <Grid>
    <Image x:Name="IsCheckedImage" Source="Images/Buttons/Button signal.png">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ToggleButton}" Value="True">
                <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=IsCheckedImage}" PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Image>
    <Image x:Name="IsUncheckedImage" Source="Images/Buttons/Button electric ns.png">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ToggleButton}" Value="False">
                <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=IsUncheckedImage}" PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Image>
    </Grid>
</ToggleButton>
```

Or is there a better / easier way to achieve this? I also read something about VisualStateManager, which I also have zero experience with...

Hope that somebody can push me in the right direction...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton"
                IsChecked="{Binding SignalButtonSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                Command="{Binding SignalButtonCommand}">
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="IsCheckedImage"
                Source="Images/Buttons/Button signal.png">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ToggleButton}"
                                            Value="True">
                    <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=IsCheckedImage}"
                                                PropertyName="Visibility"
                                                Value="Collapsed" />
                    <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=IsUncheckedImage}"
                                                PropertyName="Visibility"
                                                Value="Visible" />
                </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Image>
        <Image x:Name="IsUncheckedImage"
                Source="Images/Buttons/Button electric ns.png">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ToggleButton}"
                                            Value="False">
                    <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=IsCheckedImage}"
                                                PropertyName="Visibility"
                                                Value="Visible" />
                    <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=IsUncheckedImage}"
                                                PropertyName="Visibility"
                                                Value="Collapsed" />
                </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</ToggleButton>
```

Comment: Hey Jessica, twice in a row, you are saving the project! Thanks for the help again!